# What fastener should I use to attach an aluminium bracket to a wall?

Tags: aluminum, brackets

Is it OK to use a regular zinc plated screw when fastening an aluminum bracket to a wall?

It might seem like a silly question but I have heard that mixing metals in fastening applications can result in corrosion.

UPDATE: It seems like corrosion is only a factor when dissimilar metals are used if moisture is present. For example boats. Otherwise dissimilar metals won't react. Someone said that zinc is actually a better choice than stainless for this application. I will keep my question here but I thought I would add this update based on my latest research.

Comment: what type of wall? drywall sheet (with or without stud behind it), cinderblock, concrete,

Comment: Here's a listing of common materials.  As @Vebjorn says, zinc and aluminum are very close (anodic)...  http://www.metal-mart.com/guides/galvanic.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be fine, especially for indoor use, where there is little moisture and salt. Zinc and aluminum are pretty close galvanically, so the zinc coating should help. In fact, most bolts used on aluminum-structure airplanes are made of steel plated with zinc or cadmium ([source](http://books.google.com/books?id=a3bloqOeFhkC&pg=PA138&lpg=PA138&dq=airplane%20aluminum%20bolts&source=bl&ots=meyf6qyHbb&sig=GUBh4XjN-UKfx2t-HZvwnM2w3MQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oc5sT8DsF8230QHWgsjxBg&ved=0CGkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=airplane%20aluminum%20bolts&f=false)).